# Enter Key Triggering Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 events in my javascript,

```
$('form').submit(function (evt) {
}
$('#myButton').click(function () {
}

<button id="myButton">Button</button>
<button id="myButton2">Button2</button>
```

When I press ENTER key it always triggers  `$('#myButton').click` first then `$('form').submit` later. How browser picking the button and then invoking its click event because I have 3 buttons.

Comment: The question is why browser picking the button click

Comment: Because you are defining #myButton as id for the button and then setting up event handler for click of the same button - #myButton.

Comment: I am pressing ENTER on a textbox

Comment: This might be helpful to understand the situation https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing